# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@firebase/auth" in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am new to IONIC framework.Need to develop mobile application using IONIC 3 and firebase used to store data and for authentication. Installed all required modules through npm.

Followed below steps to create IONIC 3 app
1) ionic start TestDemo tabs
2) ionic generate page signup
3) npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
4) imported to app.module.ts

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    WelcomePage,
    LoginPage,
    SignupPage,
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ]
```

5) signup.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
})
export class SignupPage {
  @ViewChild("email") email;
  @ViewChild("mobileno") mobileno;
  @ViewChild("username") username;
  @ViewChild("password") password;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private fire: AngularFireAuth ) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignupPage');
  }
   async signup(){
    try{
    const result = await this.fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.username.value,this.password.value);
    console.log(result);
  }
    catch(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

6) signup.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>signup</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" #email></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-label floating>Mobile No</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" #mobileno></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" #username></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="password" #password></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <button ion-button round (click)="signup()">Sign Up</button>
        </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

7) ionic serve
then it giving below error

```
Error: Cannot find module "@firebase/auth"
    at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:66020:65)
    at Object.__webpack_exports__.c (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:66020:156)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:65949:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:112662:64)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:65937:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.101 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:76:76)
```

Please help on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]` where you are binding `@ViewChild("email") email;
  @ViewChild("mobileno") mobileno;
  @ViewChild("username") username;
  @ViewChild("password") password;` those can all just be variables in the scope of the page so `mobilino;` would be declared and [(ngModel)] goes where all your hashtags are.

Comment: Even I removed getting same error.
async signup(){
    //this.db.list("/ionicdemo-b6b50").push(this.username.value);
   // localStorage.setItem(""+this.username.value,""+this.password.value);
    //this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
    try{
    const result = await this.fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("test@test.com","test123");
    console.log(result);
    }catch(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }
  }

Comment: as a workaround instead of using angularfire...you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase - I have used it with my ionic project in spots where angularfire was randomly failing, even though it is javascript it works fine (i had to change `function() {` from js to `() => {` or it wouldnt work sometimes. It seems like for some reason your angularfire2 (which references the package i linked)...its not working correctly with its firebase package dependency...why im not sure...but try just using `npm firebase`....the instructions for how to use it are on that page.